# Will submit button's onclick event get invoked when submitting a form without using mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

From my simple experiment, even when I submit a `form` using keyboard enter (without using mouse to click), the `onclick` event on submit button also got invoked, as if someone clicked it.

So is this always the case?

P.S. I'm using jsx in React 15.3.2

Comment: Yes it will be.

Comment: It is onsubmit that gets invoked when you press 'enter'.

Comment: @TusharArora But my form doesn't have any `onsubmit` event. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: @StanleyLuo Does your form has input type="submit" button? If yes, then onsubmit gets fired implicitly.

Comment: @TusharArora Yes I have. So `onsubmit` gets fired implicitly, which then fires `onclick`?

Comment: @divy3993 If you can post as an answer there's 15 points for you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways click event could be triggered. If not considering any other event, binding the click event along with it (such as **onhover** = **trigger click on an element** - using JS or jQuery).

## 1. Form Submissions

In case of form, when you have **type="submit"** with Button or Input element. The form has it's type implicitly set to submit event, which submits your form.

You can try that by not adding any **type="submit"** in button or input element.

## 2. Focus & Enter Key

When you have any element focused, and if user hits enter. It will fire the click event action on that too.

Like When any link or button element have the focus currently and you hit enter instead of clicking it. It will do the same, that is fire the click event for that particular element.

Thanks

I really hope this helps you more! :)